# How does `customElements` works when i pass a constructor binded to some arguments?

Tags: html, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out why given the following class

```js
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this, ...arguments);
    }
}
```

This code doesn't works

```js
customElements.define(
    "my-custom-element",
    MyCustomElement.bind(void 0, 1, 2, 3)
);

try {
    document.body.innerHTML = `
        <my-custom-element>
            my-custom-element
        </my-custom-element>"
    ` // throws
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e) // Ilegal Constructor
}
```

While this works fine

```js
customElements.define(
    "my-custom-element-bind-ext",
    class extends MyCustomElement.bind(void 0, 1, 2, 3) {}
)

try {
    document.body.innerHTML = `
        <my-custom-element-bind-ext>
            my-custom-element-bind-ext
        </my-custom-element-bind-ext>
    ` // works fine and prints the "1, 2, 3" arguments in the console
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e) // it never gets here
}
```

###### TLDR:

Why is allowed to instantiate a custom element of a type that extends a binded class but is not allowed to instantiate the binded class itself?

###### EDIT

To be fair the snippet

```
customElements.define(
    "my-custom-element-bind-ext",
    class extends MyCustomElement.bind(void 0, 1, 2, 3) {}
)
```

doesn't work very well, indeed getters and setters aren't grabbed (if there are some), and, if the custom element extends something that trigger events like `HTMLFormElement`, predefined events aren't triggered by the custom element instance.

This leads to more question than answare! But at least it is possible to say that binding a custom element to some arguments is not a good idea.